# RegisterClientScriptInclude

Tags: c#

i use ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude to include js file after partial postback it works fine 
here :
**

> ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this, typeof(test4), "1", Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/slideshow/js/slideshow.js"));

**
but i want to load more than one js files so i did this
 **

> ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this,typeof(test4),"one",
>   Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/slideshow/js/slideshow.js"));
>   ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this, typeof(test4), "two", Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/slideshow/js/slideImg.js"));

** 
with two different string keys the first one works but the second not....please any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code works fine for me:

```
string jquery = "js/jquery-1.4.min.js";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(jquery, jquery);

string myScript = "js/myScript.js";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(myScript, myScript);
```

I put it in my OnPreRender method

Comment: i tried this method to include jquery.gomap-1.3.2.min.js & map.js files, but it didn't work for me.